# FactoryGirl override parent class attribute subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, factory-bot

I want to override the parent class using the subclass factory. For example, I want to change the subdomain of the subclass so it overrides it from the parent class.

campaign.rb file

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :campaign do
    subdomain 'thrifty'
  end
end
```

photo_upload_campaign.rb file

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :photo_upload_campaign, parent: :campaign do
    subdomain 'weekender' 
  end
end
```

step definition file

```
Given(/^there's a subdomain for a photo upload campaign campaign$/) do
  @campaign = create(:campaign)
  @photo_upload = create(:photo_upload_campaign)
  if !@campaign.subdomain.present?
    fail(ArgumentError.new('Where is the subdomain?'))
  end
end

When(/^I visit the photo upload campaign microsite subdomain url$/) do
  visit_with_subdomain microsite_home_path, subdomain: @photo_upload.subdomain
end
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do -- by specifying parent:  :campaign for the photo_upload_compaign factory you're saying it is a campaign just with subdomain set to 'weekender' by default rather than 'thrifty' - then in your test you create one of each -- so you have 2 Campaign objects , 1 with subdomain 'thrifty', one with subdomain 'weekender'  - what is the issue?

Comment: I can do `@campaign.subdomain = 'weekender'`. `@photo_upload_subdomain = @campaign.subdomain`. But that would defeat the purpose of using inheritance?

Comment: What do you think are inheriting?  `@photoupload` is not an object inheriting from `@campaign` - they are 2 completely separate objects.  The parent: :campaign in the factory definition just makes the photo_upload_campaign factory use the settings of the campaign factory unless they are overridden in the photo_upload_campaign factory -- each call to create still creates completely independent objects

Comment: Solved it by having two objects. `@photo_upload_campiagn` and `@quiz_campaign`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I could just create a factory quiz campaign and it gets all the attribute from campaign

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :quiz_campaign do
    subdomain 'weekender'
  end
end
```